# How to show data is incomplete in data analysis

Tags: data-analysis

I have a employee training data set which includes columns such as employee ID, employee full name, training data, training title and training status (pass/fail) for the past 10 years.
I am trying to do some analysis with this data but i feel like the data is incomplete meaning all training records were not put in the system properly (in practice, there is a possibility that training records were not entered into the dataset but i need to proof my hypothesis). Is there any methodology that I can use and show incompleteness of data?